# Python keeps memory fragments in local() after for loop. How to prevent it?

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, local

Memory allocation in Python seems to be keep some fragments after exiting for loops.
When I run the following snippet:

```
currentlocals = locals().copy()
for name in currentlocals:
    print(name)
del currentlocals
```

I get the following output

```
__name__
__doc__
__package__
__loader__
__spec__
__builtin__
__builtins__
_ih
_oh
_dh
In
Out
get_ipython
exit
quit
_
__
___
_i
_ii
_iii
_i1
```

From my understanding, `del` frees the allocated memory of `currentlocals`.
Since the variable `name` only exists insides the for loop, I assume it should be freed automatically when exiting the loop.
Therefore, after executing the snippet, the allocated memory should be the same as before.
However, running the snippet twice in one python script prints me an additional

```
name
_i2
```

at the end. Every additional time I run the snippet after the initial time, I get an additional `_i3`, where the number keeps counting up.
Actively using `del` to free the memory of e.g. `_i3` or `name` only deletes the current name. The next time the snippet is executed, `_i3` is missing, but instead `_i4` and `_i5` appear in the list.

Where does this memory leak come from?
I assume, that it is some kind of memory allocated for the iterating index of the for loop.
How do I prevent python from keeping parts of the working memory allocated with those objects that shouldn't exist anymore?

I am working with python3 in jupyter notebook.

Comment: A lot of those variables are maintained by `ipython/jupyter`. You don't want/need to delete those.  In a notebook only worry about large numpy arrays.

Comment: `name` does *not* only exist in the loop; it persists as a local variable *after* the loop completes as well. A `for` loop is a fancy kind of assignment statement. `name` is not yet defined the first time you call `locals()`, but it is the second time.

Comment: The problems you are seeing here are inherent to the way jupyter notebooks work. But in any case, you have a couple fundamental misunderstandings of Python: "From my understanding, del frees the allocated memory of currentlocals. Since the variable name only exists insides the for loop, I assume it should be freed automatically when exiting the loop." So *no* `del` does not free anything. `del` merely removes names from namespaces. Objects are only freed when their reference count goes to zero, which may or may not happen when you `del` a name. Also, Python does not have block scope.

Comment: All of these `_i3` etc variables are created by jupyter for its various history magics. To avoid global variabels from keeping objects around for longer than you want, the best strategy to organize your code into functions.